# I want to prefix/append some text to the description of already submitted changelist using perl or python

Tags: python, perl, perforce

I need to prefix submitted CL description with some info as shown below.

Description:
    (TOPIC : blah)

Here how it should look like

Description:
    [CPR-blah] (TOPIC : blah)

I am unable to do this with just p4 commands piped together. I was wondering if this can be achieved with perl/ python.

I have already tried below

p4 --field Description="New CL description here" change -o *changelist_number* | p4 change -i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it (using P4Python):

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()

try:
  p4.connect()
  change = p4.fetch_change(changelist_number)
  change["Description"] = "CPR-blah" + change["Description"]
  p4.save_change(change)

except P4Exception:
  for e in p4.errors:
    print e

finally:
  p4.disconnect()
```

If you're appending instead of prefixing, I think you can do that from the command line like:

```
p4 --field Description+="CPR-blah" change -o change_number | p4 change -i
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. I tried the appending one and facing error - "Can't update committed change 1867863 ". This means we cant update a already submitted changelists

Comment: You can update a submitted changelist using the `-f` flag (this would go on the `p4 change -i` since that's the part that does the update, so `p4 change -i -f`) if you're an admin, or using the `-u` flag if you're its owner.

Comment: p4 --field Description+="CPR-blah" change -o change_number | p4 change -i -u

Comment: Above command with -u flag works like charm . What i can do to prefix the same content ?

Comment: See https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.save_spectype for how to turn `save_change()` into an equivalent `p4 change -i -u` command.